# div disappear and then appear after a post function call with JQuery

Tags: jquery, post

I'm achieving an AJAX Chat, and it's almost done. What I have so far is, a div holding the messages, a textarea and a button, after clicking the send button, data go to another `.php` file through a post:

```
function send(pid){
    $.post("SetAndGet.php",{
        msgChat: $("#messagePM").val(),
        idpChat: pid
    },function(data){
        $("#messagesPM").html(data);
    });
}
```

The problem I'm asking about (and considering so weird) is that in the response, the div `messagesPM` disappreas and appears again holding the new messages. Why does it disappear and how do I fix that?

Comment: do you want your div to contain only 1 message?

Comment: no, it holds all the messages, John, I did all that, just want why the div disappears to update the messages liste?

Comment: If `messagePM` is a `div` as you suggest, then `$("#messagePM").val()` won't work.

Comment: see my answer, are you returning a HTML string with a new div for example <div id="messagesPM">NEW ERROR CONTENT</DIV>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    function send(pid){
      $.post("SetAndGet.php",{ msgChat: $("#messagePM").text(), idpChat: pid },function(data){ $("#messagesPM").append(data); });
 })
```

Firstly if $("#messagesPM") is a DIV, .val() will not return the content of the div, you must use .text() to get the text inside of a div.

Secondly using HTML() will replace the div with whatever gets returned, so use append. UNLESS you are returning a DIV html tag with its content set.

Comment: No problem, have a good day... remember to tick it as solved :P

Comment: just that, I usually use html(), that was the problem, thanks John, you been so fast and helpful, It's solved!